# Call a backingbean method with array as parameter

Tags: jsf

how can I pass a Array to a Bean in JSF.

Example:

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="bean")
...
/* Method I want to call*/
public String output(String[] strings) {
...
}
```

Jsf:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.output( ??? )}"/>
```

Comment: Just pass it in? That'll work fine if your environment supports EL 2.2. Or are you actually asking how to create an array in EL?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to ask :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create an array in EL, but you can create a string with a specific delimiter and then use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `fn:split()` to split it on the delimiter into an array.

```html
<html ... xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">
...
<h:outputText value="#{bean.output(fn:split('one,two,three', ','))}" />
```